# How to implement search in SharePoint Online between the multiple site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-search

I have have multiple site collection in SharePoint online. And I want to search the documents across all the site collections. And searching should work up to subsites as well across all the site collection. Search inside a single site collection is working fine.

```
Example:-
Site Collection 1: https://smartcircle.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev1
Site Collection 2: https://smartcircle.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev2
```

If document A is available in Dev2's subsite. And if I search from Dev1, document A should be get searchable. Can any one please help out me in this scenario? Or please advise does this search is possible across all site collections?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Search has stages upon which it operates.
If, for example, you are within a list and type something in the search bar, the Search Service will pop up results from the current List.
If, you step out and navigate to the site collection level, the Search Service will pop up results from all the lists within the site collection.
If, you step out a bit more, for example the office.com site or the sharepoint starting page, the Search Service will bring up results from all of the site collections.

MS Search Service is a Multi-Stage service that crawls and brings up results from multiple places, which in their turn depend upon where a user typed a search string.

If ,on the other hand, you wish to enrich the Search Service experience, you can deploy the [PnP Modern Search Web Parts](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/).

It's an open source projects that lets you customize the search page and add refiners for the search results, define result sources and lots of more custom functionalities that i would not be able to include within this answer.

Comment: as an update on MS Search, a user is able to search documents within sharepoint by simply pressing the `Windows Key` and typing managed metadata that is assigned to a crawled property.